# MYSQL: want to compare words to text in text field only when field has text using MATCHES AGAINST IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am comparing some text to a text field using

```
WHERE MATCH(dbase-field) AGAINST('$querystring' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE).
```

I would like to also compare the query string to another textfield but the catch is I want to exclude results where there is no match if the field has text, but I don't want to exclude results if the textfield is empty.

In other words, I can't just say:

```
WHERE MATCH(dbase-field) AGAINST('$querystring' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AND 
 MATCH(dbase-field2) AGAINST('$querystring' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

as I believe this would always filter out results when there is no match on the dbase-field2 but I only want d-basefield2 to filter when there is something in it.

What I'd like to do is (pseudo-code):

```
WHERE MATCH(dbase-field) AGAINST('$querystring' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AND 
if (there is any text in dbase-field2) {
 MATCH(dbase-field2) AGAINST('$querystring' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
}
```

Is there a way to do this in MYSQL perhaps using CASE END?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
WHERE MATCH(dbase-field) AGAINST('$querystring' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AND 
      (dbase-field2 IS NULL OR
       MATCH(dbase-field2) AGAINST('$querystring' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
      )
```